# Convergence of $V_n=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n U_i$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

I struggle to do this exercise:

Let $U_1,U_2,\dots$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables. We define
$$V_n=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n U_i$$

Show that $V_n^{1/n}$ converges almost sure and calculate the limit.

So what I thought so far:

Since I have to show almost sure convergence, I would think that I have to show this with the law of large numbers.

So $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\frac{\sqrt{V_n}}{n}=E[\sqrt{V_n}]=nE[\sqrt{U_i}]$$

Now here I'm stucked and I don't know if this is correct. Thanks for help.

Comment: If the $U_i$ are non-zero a.s. then you might consider $W_n = \log V_n$. Then the law of large numbers is surely useful to compute the limit of $n^{-1}W_n = \log V_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Why do you consider the **square** root of $V_n$ ? It's the $n$-th root... Mathjax for this is : $\sqrt[n]{V_n}$

Comment: @JeanMarie Giving the code itself (that is, "\sqrt[n]{V_n}") may be more useful than the typeset and rendered version.

Comment: @Clement C. You are right !

Comment: I think that the $U_i$ random variables have to be non-negative. Otherwise, $V_n^{1/n}$ might be undefined (what is $(-3)^{1/n}$, for instance?). In such a case, it is enough to use the usual $\exp$/$\log$ machinery.

Comment: Following Jack D'Aurizio's (good) answer below: are you sure you fully specified the question? I.e., was there any further assumption on the distribution of the $U_i$'s?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes. There wasn't any further assumption on the distribution of the $U_i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $U_i > 0$, we may define $X_i$ as $\log U_i$.
 Assuming that $\mathbb{E}[\log U_i]<+\infty$, the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) gives
$$ \frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{n}\to \mathbb{E}[\log U_i] $$
and by exponentiating back
$$ V_n^{1/n} \to \exp\left(\mathbb{E}[\log U_i]\right). $$

Comment: May be me overthinking it, but shouldn't there an assumption on the distribution of the $U_i$'s, though? What about $U_i = e^{X_i}$, with $X_i$ being Cauchy?

Comment: @ClementC. Strictly speaking, a Cauchy distribution does not have an expectation, $\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ is not a $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ function. Here I am requesting that $U_i>0$ and that the density function of $\log U_i$ belongs to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem -- your answer needs that assumption to work, but I'm not sure it's because it's required for the original statement to even be true (i.e., the OP did not fully specify the question). (Sorry, I hadn't seen you had already made the extra assumption in your answer. My doubt is -- is that assumption necessary?)

Comment: @ClementC.: I understand that, I just worked in the most reasonable assumptions, since otherwise the OP's question may not make sense, as remarked in the comments.

Comment: I agree -- sorry, I should probably asked that to the OP to begin with. (+1)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you very much!